# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow—blowfish algorithm

Tags: vb.net, blowfish

When I execute this code:

```
Dim bytearray() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\Fery Ferdiansyah\Desktop\asd\asd.txt")
Dim key() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("swagger")
Dim bf As New blowfish2(key)
```

this syntax  `y = S(0, a) + S(1, b)` in this function causes arithmetic overflow:

```
Private Function F(ByVal x As UInteger) As UInteger
    Dim a As UShort
    Dim b As UShort
    Dim c As UShort
    Dim d As UShort
    Dim y As UInteger

    d = CUShort((x And &HFF))
    x >>= 8
    c = CUShort((x And &HFF))
    x >>= 8
    b = CUShort((x And &HFF))
    x >>= 8
    a = CUShort((x And &HFF))
    y = S(0, a) + S(1, b)
    y = y Xor S(2, c)
    y = y + S(3, d)

    Return y
End Function
```

Could anyone help me to fix this function?

Comment: What is the code the function S?

Comment: function S is a 2-dimensional array in integer

Comment: Check this question as it is closely related with yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874130/difference-between-casting-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net

Comment: but i can't figure out whats wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of adding two integers (`Int32`) has to be stored into a `Int64` to be sure that the result can be stored without overflow.

So in this case your method should return a `UInt64` and y should be `UInt64` as well.

Comment: i try to do this Private Function F(ByVal x As UInteger) As UInt64 and dim y as UInt64. but yet, it still pop up the same problem

Comment: Please, add the exception details (message, stacktrace, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable integer overflow checking ([Advanced Compiler Settings Dialog Box (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/07bysfz2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) or declare `y` as a UInt64 then

```
Return CUInt(y And &HFFFFFFFF)
```

Comment: i have tried it, but no difference between declare  y  as a UInt64 or just UInteger

Comment: If there are any values in S greater than &H7FFFFFFF then you will need to declare S as an array of unsigned integers. What are the actual values from S which are giving the error?

Comment: i declared S as an array of integers