# Forced Casting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, casting

I have tried to find a function/operator for vb.net that does the same as the following in c:
uint8_t value1 = 200;
int8_t value2 = (int8_t)value1;

-> value2 should be some negative value

since there are bitwise or, xor, and, not, i'd hope there is also a clean way to do a cast based on the binary, not the decimal value.

I'd need this for 8, 16 & 32 bit integers and in both directions.

If u are asking yourself why, i am developing a custom communication library for a microcontroller and the data sent is allways unsigned bytes and after masking, parity checking and arranging the data, i end up with unsigned integer values that need to be cast back to their original type.

Now i know, that i could implement this by substracting some value if the input value gets bigger than 127... but that is just messy and slow, so i was hoping there is somewhere a function that just tells the compiler to do a direct cast without checking if it makes sense.

I'd really appreciate your input.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in VB.NET that would do that.  You may have to go via the `BitConverter` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB, overflow are checked by default (C# is not). You'll have to disable it in the compiler settings (I think it's in the Advanced Compile Options. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1874190/130611) could help you out.

After that, you can easely just convert from one to the other.

```
    Dim a As UInt16
    Dim b As Int16

    a = 65530
    b = a

    Console.WriteLine(b) ' Prints -6
```

Comment: Lovely thanks, i think that is going to make my life a whole lot easier :)