# Conversion an Int to two Shorts returns padded data / negative values

Tags: c#, type-conversion, int, short, bitconverter

I have a simple piece of code to convert an Int to two `short`s:

```
public static short[] IntToTwoShorts(int a)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    return new short[] { BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0), BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 2) };
}
```

If I pass in **1851628330** (**‭0x6E5D 9B2A**‬) the result is:

```
{short[2]}
    [0]: -25814
    [1]: 28253
```

The problem is that **-25814** is **0xFFFF 9B2A**

I've tried various flavours including bit shifting. What's going on? That result isn't a `short`, and doesn't have **16** *bits*!

Comment: "The problem is that -25814 is 0xFFFF 9B2A" Not if you're regarding it as a short. (It's not clear why you're going via BitConverter, or what you expect the results to be. You should definitely make the latter clear in the question.)

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the least significant two bytes can't really be made into a signed short. '9' = 1001b means that the sign bit is set, so it represents a negative value as a `short`. Can you return the 16 bit numbers as `ushort`?

Comment: I'm converting old code that used CopyMem....It was so easy. I just want the bit pattern in two shorts - I did start with using Bitwise OR but had the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `ushort` when combining back two `short` into `int`:

```
public static short[] IntToTwoShorts(int a) {
  unchecked {
    return new short[] {
       (short) a,
       (short) (a >> 16)
    };
  }
}

public static int FromTwoShorts(short[] value) {
  unchecked {
    if (null == value)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    else if (value.Length == 1)
      return (ushort)value[0]; // we don't want binary complement here 
    else if (value.Length != 2)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value"); 

    return (int)((value[1] << 16) | (ushort)value[0]); // ... and here
  }
}
```

The cause of the unexpected behaviour is that *negative numbers* (like `-25814`) are represented as [binary complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and so you have the *same* value (`-25814`) *represented differently* in different integer types:

```
-25814 ==             0x9b2a // short, Int16
-25814 ==         0xffff9b2a //   int, Int32
-25814 == 0xffffffffffff9b2a //  long, Int64
```

Some tests

```
int a = 1851628330;
short[] parts = IntToTwoShorts(a);

Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", parts)}]");
Console.WriteLine($"{FromTwoShorts(parts)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{FromTwoShorts(new short[] { -25814 })}");
Console.WriteLine($"0x{FromTwoShorts(new short[] { -25814 }):X}");
```

Outcome:

```
[-25814, 28253]
1851628330
39722
0x9B2A
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem with something like this:

```
public static short[] IntToTwoShorts(int a)
{
    short retVar[2];
    //Upper 16 byte masked with 0x0000FFFF
    retVar[0] = (short) (a >> 16) & (65535);
    //Lower 16 byte masked with 0x0000FFFF
    retVar[1] = (short) (a >> 0) & (65535);

    return retVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the code (although there may be more [efficient ways to do split integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873443/314291)). By attempting to represent an `int` as two signed 16 bit shorts, you now need to consider that the sign bit could be present in both `shorts`.  Hence the comment that `ushort[]` would be a more appropriate choice of representation of the two 16 bit values.

The problem seems to be with the understanding of why a 4 byte signed integer (DWORD) can't be effectively represented in two 2 byte signed shorts (WORD)s.

> The problem is that -25814 is 0xFFFF 9B2A

This isn't true - you've represented `-25814` as a `short`, so it can't possibly be `0xFFFF 9B2A` - that's a 32 bit representation. Its 16 bit representation is just `9B2A`.

If you open up the Calculator on Windows, and set the mode to programmer, and tinker with the `HEX` and `DEC` bases, and then flipping between `DWORD` and `WORD` representations of the values, you should see that the 16 bit values you've extracted from the 32 bit int are correctly represented (provided that you understand the representation):

Your original 32 bit Integer (DWORD) is 1851628330:

[image: Original DWord]

The high word 28253 doesn't have the sign bit set, so you seem satisfied with the conversion to 6E5D:

[image]

However, if the low word is interpreted as a signed short, then you'll find that it's bit sign is set, so hence it reported as a negative value. However, the representation (bits, and hex) does correctly represent the last 16 bits of your original 32 bit int.

[image]